# No puedo alinear el logo con la NavBar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

El problema es que la imagen que utilicé como logo, se veía demasiado pequeña, por lo que decidí agrandarla y al hacer esto la imagen se desalineó.

La cosa es que me gustaría que quede alineada, grande, que no afecte el "Responsive" y sin agrandar la Barra lo máximo posible ya que en el tamaño que está ahora, me agrada bastante.

[image: EN CHIQUITO]

[image: EN GRANDE]

```css
/* Navegacion */
#tf-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: auto;
}
.navbar-brand img {
   height: 30px; /*Aqui es donde cambio y se desalinea*/
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 8px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffcc33;
}
```

```html
<nav id="tf-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="..."></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#tf-home" class="scroll">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tf-services" class="scroll">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tf-about" class="scroll">Quienes somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tf-blog" class="scroll">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tf-contact" class="scroll">Contacto</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio. Y léete [ask] para mejorar tus preguntas. ¿Que versión de bootstrap estas usando?

Comment: Mira si cambiando esto `<a class="navbar-brand"` por esto `<a class="navbar-left"` te funciona mejor

Comment: @masterguru Sip, muchisimas gracias, fue mejor que varias soluciones que encontre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución, aceptada por el OP en los comentarios de la pregunta, para alinear el logo grande dentro de la barra de navegación de bootstrap navbar ha sido cambiar la clase de este elemento:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="..."></a>
```

dejándolo de este modo:

```
<a class="navbar-left" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="..."></a>
```

Es decir, se ha cambiado la clase `navbar-brand` por la clase `navbar-left`.

Esta solución fué encontrada en [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333342/10382744) del sitio de SO en inglés, y la pongo como respuesta para que conste aquí.

Tal como comenta @JheymanMejia y como se ve en la misma respuesta en ingles, parece ser que esto solo se aplica en la versión 3 de bootstrap.

Comment: Buena respuesta, aclarar que únicamente aplica para la versión 3 de Bootstrap.